# error build: Undefined symbol: _SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkSourceIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, game-development

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXajl.png)

Xcode v14.0.1
using unity ads, chartboost, mintegral, ironsource, admob
error build: Undefined symbol: _SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkSourceIdentifier

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hit same error myself recently in Xcode 14.0.

I can't find anything specific in the release notes for it, but the issue was resolved after updating Xcode.  Jumped to 14.2, but 14.1 may have included the change as well.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your SDKs may not be compatible with your current Xcode version. Try updating your Xcode accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).